# Number of places in a row where a boy and a girl are standing next to each other.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose that $7$ boys and $13$ girls line up in a row. Let $S$ be the number of places in the row where a boy and a girl are standing next to each other. For example,for the row $GBBGGGBGBGGGBGBGGBGG$ we have $S=12$. If all possible orders of these $20$ people are considered,what is the average value of $S$?

I've been stuck on this problem for the last hours and the only thing I was capable to notice is that if we have a group of $m$ boys and $1$ girl ,then $S=2m/(m+1)$ but then if I add the number of girls the problem becomes much harder...

I know  this s not a big attempt,but it's the only usefull thing I've done...the rest is just about considering small cases to seek for some pattern which isn't necessary to show.

Comment: Cheating and using a computer gave me the answer of $\frac{91}{10}$. Not sure yet of a nice way to show this mathematically.

Comment: I would have thought that if you had $m$ boys and one girl then $E[S] = \frac{2m}{m+1}$

Comment: @Henry yeah sorry I've put it in the wrong way .

Comment: I need some time to think about the answers before asking specific questions,but thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We make the problem more explicit. Consider positions $2$ to $20$. We say that there is a *transition* at position $i$ if the people at positions $i-1$ and $i$ are of different sexes. Let $Y$ be the number of transitions. We find $E(Y)$.

We could in principle find the distribution of $Y$, and then find $E(Y)$ in the usual way. That may be very difficult.

Instead, we use the *method of indicator random variables*. For $i=2$ to $20$, let $X_i=1$ if there is a transition at $i$, and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then 
$$Y=X_2+X_3+\cdots+X_{20},$$
and by the linearity of expectation
$$E(Y)=E(X_2)+E(X_3)+\cdots+E(X_{20}).$$
Note that by symmetry all the $E(X_i)$ are equal. So it is enough to find $E(X_2)$.

There is a transition at $2$ if we have boy at $1$ and girl at $2$, or the opposite.

The probability of boy at $1$ is $\frac{7}{20}$. Given there is a boy at $1$, the probability of a girl at $2$ is $\frac{13}{19}$, so the probability of a BG transition is $\frac{7}{20}\cdot \frac{13}{19}$.

Now find the probability of a GB transition at $2$, and finish the calculation.

Comment: I've never seen this method before,it's quite affascinating ! Do we have that all $E(X_i)$ are equal because we can consider every position from $2$ to $20$ as the beginning of our sequence,hence we have the same case every time (I hope I have been clear) ?

Comment: I think of it as because all permutations are equally likely.  Actually, when I first wrote it up, as you may check from the edit history, i used $i-1$ and $i$ instead of $1$ and $2$. Same probability calculation. The method of indicator random variables is used quite a lot. The advantage, when it can be used, is that it bypasses the sometimes very difficult problem of finding the distribution.

Comment: One last question :is there some kind of relation between generating function and the method you've described above? Btw thanks for your time.

Comment: I cannot think of a relationship, but generating functions are such a powerful tool that there very well may be. note that Henry's very nice solution implicitly expressed $Y$ as a sum of random variables. We can think of $Y$ as a sum $B_1+\cdots+B_7$, where $B_i$ is the number of transitions Boy $i$ is involved in. The $B_i$ are not indicator random variables, but their means are easy to calculate, so again it is linearity of expectation that is being exploited,

Answer (score 3):

If there are $b$ boys and $g$ girls, then for an individual boy, the expected number of girls on the immediate left is $\dfrac{g}{g+(b-1)+1} =  \dfrac{g}{g+b}$, the number on the right is the same by symmetry, and there are $b$ boys so $$E[S] = \dfrac{2gb}{g+b}$$ which gives $\frac{2 \times 13 \times 7}{13+7}= \frac{91}{10}$ in your example.

Comment: Nice answer @Henry. It agrees with what I had worked out so far.

Comment: How can someone notice the pattern you described above ?

Comment: @Nameless I used linearity of expectation, which is fairly common in such questions.  Inserting an extra (non-)person on the far left is less common, but often helps, as in http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1114/990